# Tkinter treeview Scrollbars not displayed correctly

Tags: tkinter

I'm wondering why the scrollbar of the treeview are not filling the x and y axis with the following code.
The only appear in the middle of the axis

Any idea ?

Thanks

```
class DataTable(ttk.Treeview):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        scroll_Y = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=self.yview)
        scroll_X = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="horizontal", command=self.xview)
        self.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll_Y.set, xscrollcommand=scroll_X.set)
        scroll_Y.pack(side="bottom", fill="y")
        scroll_X.pack(side="right", fill="x")
        self.stored_dataframe = pd.DataFrame()
        self.bind("<Double-1>", lambda event: self.onDoubleClick(event))

    def set_datatable(self, dataframe: pd.DataFrame):
        self.delete(*self.get_children())
        columns = list(dataframe.columns)
        self.__setitem__("column", columns)
        self.__setitem__("show", "headings")

        for col in columns:
            self.heading(col, text=col)
        
        df_rows = dataframe.to_numpy().tolist()
        for row in df_rows:
            self.insert("", "end", values=row)
        return None


class ContentPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        
        #TreeView
        self.data_table = DataTable(parent)
        self.data_table.place(relx=0, rely=0, relheight=0.90, relwidth=1)

        # some process to create a pandas dataframe
        
        self.data_table.set_datatable(dataframe=df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have put the scrollbars in wrong sides.

Correct packing:

```py
scroll_Y.pack(side="right", fill="y") # vertical one at the right side
scroll_X.pack(side="bottom", fill="x") # horizontal one at the bottom side
```